# How to make firewall-cmd call with cron

Tags: linux

Hello is there any way that i can execute firewall-cmd call with crontab?
Basicly i want to open port at given time and after some days close that port

```
* * * * * root firewall-cmd --add-port=38116/tcp
```

Answer (score 1):

The better answer for your problem is creating a script that checks if the port is open or not, if it's not, you open it, else, you close it.
Cron will execute your script by the desired time. There is no way you can do both open and close on the same crontab file.